# How to use passport-sharepoint to connect to Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint-2013

Can anyone provide a good example of how to use `passport-sharepoint` to connect to an instance of Sharepoint 2013?

I have installed `passport-sharepoint` along with all the dependent modules:

- `passport`
- `jwt-simple`
- `oauth`
- `passport-oauth`
- `pkginfo`

I've imported the module with:

```js
sppp = require("passport-sharepoint");
```

How do I proceed?  The [examples supplied here](https://github.com/QuePort/passport-sharepoint) are not complete.

Thank you.